# Error Only from Java Spark ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark, syntax-error

I am trying to run few SQL queries using Java Spark libraries.
All SQLs are running fine except one:

```
(SELECT CMM.BENEFIT, (length(CMM.HIERARCHY) - length(replace(CMM.HIERARCHY,'>','')) + 1) BNFT_CMPNT_LVL_NBR, LBCX.SERVICE_DEF_TGT_CD, LBCX.SERVICE_DEF_DESC, LBCX.BENEFIT_CMPNT_DESC, LBCX.SERVICE_DEF_TGT_CD, CMM.HIERARCHY FROM EHUB_PROD_RAW.cs90_master_mapping CMM INNER JOIN EHUB_PROD_RAW.wpd_spider_benefit_hierarchy WSBH ON CMM.HIERARCHY = WSBH.HIERARCHY INNER JOIN EHUB_PROD_RAW.legacy_bnft_cmpnt_xref LBCX ON CMM.BENEFIT = LBCX.BENEFIT_CMPNT_NM)
```

Same query runs fine from SQL Developer!

I am guessing something with hidden char or quotes.
Any guidance please.

Comment: Without the complete text of the error message we cannot possibly help.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the same column twice:

```
( select
  cmm.benefit,
  ( length(cmm.hierarchy) - length(replace(cmm.hierarchy,'>','') ) + 1 ) bnft_cmpnt_lvl_nbr,
  lbcx.service_def_tgt_cd,
  lbcx.service_def_desc,
  lbcx.benefit_cmpnt_desc,
  --lbcx.service_def_tgt_cd, <-- this one is duplicated
  cmm.hierarchy
  from
  ehub_prod_raw.cs90_master_mapping cmm
  inner join ehub_prod_raw.wpd_spider_benefit_hierarchy wsbh on cmm.hierarchy = wsbh.hierarchy
  inner join ehub_prod_raw.legacy_bnft_cmpnt_xref lbcx on cmm.benefit = lbcx.benefit_cmpnt_nm
)
```

If you need it twice in the result set, then you should use aliases. I think SQL Developer will auto-alias it by appending a `_1` to one of the ambiguous columns.

Comment: Travis, thanks. That was The problem. Yes, SQL Developer was automatically adding _1 for the second iteration of the same column.